# Is `/etc/tty0` in Ubuntu the file used by `init` and `getty`?

Tags: linux, tty, getty

APUE says

> The BSD terminal login procedure has not changed much over the past 35 years. The system administrator creates a ﬁle, usually `/etc/ttys`, that has one line per terminal
>   device.  Each line speciﬁes the name of the device and other parameters that are passed
>   to the `getty` program.  When the system is bootstrapped, the kernel creates process ID 1, the `init` process, and
>   it is `init` that brings the system up in multiuser mode. The `init` process reads the ﬁle
>   `/etc/ttys` and, for every terminal device that allows a login, does a `fork` followed by
>   an `exec` of the program `getty`.

My Ubuntu doesn't have `/etc/ttys` but `/etc/tty0`

```
$ ls /etc/tty*
/etc/tty0
$ file /etc/tty0  
/etc/tty0: ASCII text
$ cat /etc/tty0  
tty0

$ dpkg -S /etc/tty0
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /etc/tty0
```

Does  `/etc/tty0` work the same as `/etc/ttys`?

In general, what is the relation between  `/etc/tty0` and `/dev/tty0`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I don’t think `/etc/tty0` is used in Ubuntu, I’m not sure where that file came from on your system.

With `sysvinit`, the equivalent to `/etc/ttys` is `/etc/inittab`. You can see an example of an `inittab` with `getty` settings in [Debian’s version](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/sysvinit/blob/master/debian/share/inittab).

With systemd, there is no single equivalent file. `getty` setup is managed using the `getty@` and `getty-serial@` services.

Comment: In Unix `inittab` was only the equivalent to `ttys` for about three quarters of a decade.  In the real System 5 `init` system, by 1988 this functionality had been removed from `inittab` and given to the Service Access Facility, which could start/stop services at runtime.  https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2018/11/msg00616.html

Comment: @JdeBP indeed; I was only considering Linux’s history, with `sysvinit`. (I should address Upstart too, since we’re talking about Ubuntu, but I’m not familiar enough with that.)